# $f \in D\left[x\right]$ is invertible iff $f \in D$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

If $D$ is a domain, I must show that $f \in D\left[x\right]$ is invertible iff $f \in D$.

Is it important that $D$ is a domain? It would happen if $D$ is a ring?

Comment: What did you try? What's your thought process?

Comment: If $D$ is not a domain, then $f\in D$ could be a zero divisor and not a unit

Comment: This is false. Clearly $0\in D$, but $0$ is not invertible, neither in $D$ nor in $D[x]$, unless $D$ is the zero ring.

Comment: I don't understand why $-3$ downvotes for the OP. The OP is asking a question about the problem hypotheses.

Comment: The correct statement would be, for a domain $D$ the invertible elements of $D[X]$ are precisely the invertible elements of $D$ (interpreted as constant polynomials).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element zero is never a unit of a ring, so let's only consider nonzero elements as potential units.

First note that if $R$ is a ring and $h\in R[x]$ then

- $h\in R{\,\setminus}\{0\}$ implies $\deg(h)=0$.$\\[4pt]$

  $h\in R[x]{\,\setminus}R$ implies $\deg(h) > 0$.

Next show that if $D$ is a domain and $f,g$ are nonzero elements of $D[x]$ then
$$\deg(fg)=\deg(f)+\deg(g)$$
Regarding your initial statement, your claim (corrected to exclude zero) was that if $D$ is a domain then

- $f\in D[x]$ is a unit iff $f\in D{\,\setminus}\{0\}$.

First consider the "only if" direction.

Thus let $D$ be a domain and suppose $f\in D[x]$ is a unit.

Then $fg=1$ for some $g\in D[x]$, hence 
$$0=\deg(1)=\deg(fg)=\deg(f)+\deg(g)$$
so we can't have $\deg(f) > 0$, thus we must have $f\in D{\,\setminus}\{0\}$.

Hence if $D$ is a domain, $f\in D[x]$ is a unit only if $f\in D{\,\setminus}\{0\}$.

To show that the "if" direction can fail, suppose $D$ is a domain but not a field. Then there must exist a nonzero element $f\in D$ which is not a unit in $D$. Let $f\in D$ be a nonzero nonunit of $D$ and suppose $f$ is a unit of $D[x]$.

Then $fg=1$ for some $g\in D[x]$ with $g\not\in D$, but then
$$0=\deg(1)=\deg(fg)=\deg(f)+\deg(g)=0+\deg(g)=\deg(g) > 0$$
contradiction.

So for the case where $D$ is a domain, you have "only if" but not "iff".

For the case where the ring of coefficients is not a domain, the "only if" direction can also fail.

For example, let $R=\mathbb{Z}_4$ and let $f$ in $R[x]$ be given by $f=2x+1$.$\;$Then 
$$
f^2=(2x+1)^2=4x^2+4x+1=0+0+1=1
$$
so $f$ is a unit in $R[x]$, but $f\not\in R$.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in a comment, the precise statement should be that for a domain $D$ one has $D[X]^\times=D^\times$, where $R^\times$ denotes the multiplicative group (or set of invertible elements) of a ring $R$.

All you need for this is the relation $\deg(PQ)=\deg(P)+\deg(Q)$ for $P,Q\in D[X]$, where $\deg(P)\in\{-\infty\}\cup\Bbb N$ is the degree, taken to be $-\infty$ (only) for $P=0$, and addition produces $-\infty$ whenever one of its arguments is so. This relation is easily established under the hypothesis that $D$ is a domain, since in the computation of $PQ$ there can be no additive cancellation in degree $\deg(P)+\deg(Q)$, the only contribution being the product of the leading terms of $P$ and $Q$, and the product of their leading coefficients cannot be $0$ because it is computed in the domain$~D$.

So here is the argument for $D[X]^\times=D^\times$. Since the *only* addition of two elements of $\{-\infty\}\cup\Bbb N$ producing the result $0$ is $0+0=0$, one has $\deg(PQ)=0\iff\deg(P)=0\land\deg(Q)=0$. So $PQ=1$ implies that $P$ and $Q$ are (nonzero) constant polynomials whose constant terms are mutually inverse elements of$~D$, in other words $D[X]^\times\subseteq D^\times$. But conversely it is obvious that mutually inverse elements of$~D$ become mutually inverse elements of $D[X]$ when viewed as constant polynomials: $D^\times\subseteq D[X]^\times$.